# register docker container to host network dns

Tags: networking, docker, dns, host

Good Day

I want to know whether there is a way to dynamically add a docker container to the host networks' DNS server.

The issue is I have an image I want to host multiple times for test and UAT purposes. I'm using traefik to discover them dynamically within the docker network.

All I need to do is have them dynamically added to the DNS server or have them picked up by the domain as a host. When the dev team then needs to access the machine all they need to do is type in the name of the server, eg app.uat.domain/app.develop.domain, and carry on without me having to update the dns records manually the whole time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not a wildcard dns entry, `*.docker.domain` could map to the docker host where traefik would process `app.uat.docker.domain`.

Comment: I'll look into it today. Also will need to try and register that to the dns server from a remote pc

Comment: Just as an aside, it is a _container_ that you probably want to have accessible via dns. An image is really just a collection of files on disk. You can have an image with no container.

Comment: @programmerq Thanks for correcting me on that. Will update the post

Comment: @BMitch It seems the teams' requirements have changed a bit, we need to have it dynamically change the domain name and not just the given docker.domain

Comment: Do you need to change the complete domain name or just the subdomain?

Comment: I need to change as new services pop up on different domain names. Currently I'm bodging it with powershell scripts and registering it to the dns server. If someone has a better solution please let me know